# Как забрать нужную информацию по ключу из html-body электронного письма

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Прошу помощи.
Есть [код](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/gmail-to-google-sheets-script/blob/master/gmailt-to-sheets.gs) (оригинал).
Он забирает письма из ящика по лейблу и сохраняет в Таблицу.
Я пытаюсь вытаскивать **НАЛЕТУ** по ключу после двоеточия с помощью такого:

```
var htmlBody = msg.getBody();
var gruppa = htmlBody.match(/<b>Группа поддержки: (.+?)<.b>/)||[];
var long = htmlBody.match(/Подробное описание:<br>\n(.+?)<.div>/m)||[];
```

из вот такого отрезка:

```
<b>Группа поддержки: XXXXXXX</b><br>
Подробное описание:<br>
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
```

Теперь к сути. Текст за ключом "Группа поддержки:" извлекается нормально, т.к. и ключ и текст находятся в одной строке (без переносов).
А вот после "Подробное описание:
" я забрать значение не могу, т.к. там перенос.

Если вставить html письма в ячейку таблицы и оттуда матчить, то всё получается. **Но налету из ящика нет.**

Я думаю, что дело в /n, не могу понять чем её заменить.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
msg.getBody().replaceAll('\n', " ").replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
```

`replaceAll('\n', " ")` убирает переносы.

`replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` убирает множественные пробелы (если не нужно - уберите).

`trim()` убирает пробелы в начале и в конце текста (если не нужно - уберите)

**UPDATE 11.04**

Правильней и короче, как посоветовал contributorpw

`replaceAll(/[\r\n]/, " ")`

Comment: `replaceAll(/[\r\n]/, " ")`